# What's the relation between different Touch install instructions for the Nexus 7?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

There are two different instructions (at least as long as you use Nexus 7). One at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation, one at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install.

The former seems to point at slightly older files.

Answer (score 2):

The Nexus7 Project and the Ubuntu Touch Project is different. The former link directs you to the installation of Ubuntu Desktop in Nexus 7 while the latter directs you to install the touch-friendly Ubuntu Touch project on Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4, Nexus 7 and Nexus 10.